# Why do I get a 403 Unauthorized when I try to create a topic on IBM Message Hub

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, message-hub

I created a new instance of IBM Message Hub on Bluemix and can use the Kafka Java client to connect to it (from my laptop) and list topics.  What I *cannot* do is create a topic via the administrative REST APIs (linebreaks added for clarity):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -H "X-Auth-Token: [value from 'password' field of credentials shown on Bluemix Service credentials]"
    -d "{ \"name\": \"topic1\" }"
    https://kafka-admin-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:443/admin/topics
```

...which results in this:

```
{
    "error_code":403,
    "message":"Unauthorized"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm an idiot.  The `api_key` from the Bluemix Service credentials was staring me in the face the whole time I was trying to use `password`.  Problem solved.